# Spark on EC2 - S3 endpoint for Scala not resolving

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, spark-ec2

Hi I have been able to setup successfully a Spark Cluster on AWS EC2 for 2 ongoing months but recently I started getting the following error in the creation script. It's basically failing in setting up the Scala packages and not resolving the source S3 endpoint:

```
--2017-02-28 17:51:30--  (try: 6)  http://s3.amazonaws.com/spark-related-packages/scala-2.10.3.tgz
Connecting to s3.amazonaws.com (s3.amazonaws.com)|52.216.0.83|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

This is my source Spark version in Github

```
https://github.com/amplab/spark-ec2/archive/branch-2.0.zip
```

And the above Scala error comes from the init.sh in

```
spark-ec2/scala/init.sh
```

Can someone fix that S3 endpoint in the Github directory or is it no longer supported from the open-source Spark community?

Comment: AWS S3 is currently (28/Feb/17, 18:25 UTC) down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon AWS is facing huge outage today, affecting mainly S3 services. Check https://status.aws.amazon.com/ for news.